# How to filter a record depending of the user connected using Laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-6, laravel-query-builder

I have the next table..

[image]

The IDOP column is a key that I'm using for connect in my app instead of email... I would like to be able for filter the IDOP of each user... So the user should only be able to see the rows with 
of its corresponding IDOP, how could I filter only his IDOP?

this is the function of my datatable

```
$('#user_contactabilidadasesor').DataTable({
processing: true,
"scrollX": true,
//serverSide: true,
ajax: {
url: "{{ route('contactabilidadasesor.index') }}",
},
columns: [
{
data: 'idop',
name: 'l.idop',
className: 'uniqueClassName'
},
{
data: 'idop_asesor',
name: 'idop_asesor',
searchable: false, render: function ( data, type, row ) {
              if (data == null){ return ''; }else{return (row['idop_asesor'] + ' ' + row['ape_asesor'])};
            },
className: 'uniqueClassName'
}
],
});
```

And this is my query

```
public function index(Request $request)
{


    if($request->ajax())
    {
        $data = DB::table('tbl_lista_contactabilidad as a')
    ->select('a.id','a.postventaatcs_id')
    ->leftjoin('tbl_equipo_postventaatcs as h','h.id','=','a.postventaatc_id')
    ->leftjoin('users as l','l.id','=','h.asesor_id')
    ->select(array('a.id','l.name as idop_asesor','l.apellido as ape_asesor','l.idop'));

        return DataTables::of($data)
                ->addColumn('action', function($data){
                    $button = '<button type="button" name="edit" id="'.$data->id.'" class="edit btn btn-primary btn-sm">Auditar</button>';
                    //$button .= '&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<button type="button" name="edit" id="'.$data->id.'" class="delete btn btn-danger btn-sm">Delete</button>';
                    return $button;
                })
                ->rawColumns(['action'])
                ->make(true);

    }

    return view('contactabilidadasesor');
}
```

Comment: Add to your query `->where('IDOP', auth()->user()->IDOP)`

Comment: It's showing me only the records that doesn't have IDOPs

Comment: auth()->user()->IDOP <--- this is and example. there you have to add IDOP value which you waqnt to filter. Where you are saving your IDOP value for the user ?

Comment: I'm saving each IDOP in the table users, but I want to see only the rows with the IDOP of each user connected

Comment: It works!! but... only if I put the specific IDOP.. But I can't put each Idop of each person in the query.. It should be automatic

Comment: i don't understand your question well. If you need to filter by multiple IDOP instead of where() you have to use whereIn('IDOP', [array of filtering idops])

Comment: I did it... thanks a lot for your help... It works like you said.. If you want post the answer.. I will score you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For filtering you have to use ->where('IDOP', auth()->user()->IDOP) (for single user) of ->whereIn('IDOP', [array of filtering idops]) for multiple IDOPs